# Aligning elements together on same row html

Tags: html, css

In my application I have the following code

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search for something..." data-inset="true">
        </ul>

        <a href="#popupNested" style="text-align: right" data-rel="popup"  data-transition="pop"><span class="material-icons"> filter_alt </span></a>
```

These 2 elements are currently on 2 sperate rows. How can I make them in the same horizontal row?

Comment: use this on the css: `ul { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Nope that doesnt do it, tried after wrapping the anchor tag as well

Comment: forgot to add the block. It workign perfectly fine for me and is a common way to do it

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` is a `block level element`. Means it will be displayed below other elements and the following element will be displayed below the `unordered list`. If you change the `ul` to an `inline-block element`, it will go inline with other inline elements such as a link `a`.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```